# Which macro definition could I use to check if my OpenCV lib support the cv::imshow interface?

Tags: opencv

sometimes, the compiled OpenCV lib did not include the Highgui module, so imshow could not be used, which macro definition  could check this? and I could use it like this:

```
#ifdef XXX
  // the lib support image show
  cv::imshow("xxx", mat);
#else
  // do nothing
#endif
```

Comment: The buildsystem [generates header `cvconfig.h`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/cmake/templates/cvconfig.h.in) which will have macros reflecting the [configured GUI implementation](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L1159). Relevant ones appear to be `HAVE_QT` `HAVE_WIN32UI` `HAVE_COCOA` `HAVE_GTK` -- if at least one is defined, you should have a build with highgui backend present. You'll have to test it out and do your research, no guarantees.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCV does not officially provide support for "feature macros", so what you are asking for is not really a robust, portable or future-proof way of using OpenCV.

The [`highgui.hpp` header `#define`s the `OPENCV_HIGHGUI_HPP` include guard](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/highgui/include/opencv2/highgui.hpp#L44) which you may check for, but again, this could hypothetically be renamed or removed in a future version, especially if OpenCV adopts C++20 modules.

In any case, the use of MACROs and preprocessor directives is highly discouraged. A better approach would be to keep some user specified compile-time or runtime boolean flag to determine whether or not to issue the display calls or design the API such that display calls can be made external to your actual (library) code which will not depend on highgui at all.

Answer (score 0):

i think HAVE_OPENCV_XXX is all you need, for example HAVE_OPENCV_HIGHGUI

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).